# What is /= in a Fortran if statement

Tags: fortran

I am converting some fortran to other languages, and have come across an if statement like

```
  ELSEIF ( param/=2 ) THEN
```

My gut feeling is that it looks like a modulus to see if the parameter is even? Either that, or /= is a != or <> that I never used when programming fortran years ago.

Last, I can't remember if fortran still needs to be all upper case, or whether that was an F77 requirement, which was deprecated in F90?

Comment: It means *not equal*, and your question title is very confusing.  Or possibly just very confused.

Comment: And these days Fortran is case indifferent, so, for example, `ARC` and `arC` (and all variations of case you care to derive) name the same thing.  But you can make your code look like it might be written in something screamingly modern like Java.

Comment: The title asks what /= is in a fortran if statement.  the example code is part of an if statement.  Does the example code look like it's not about use of /= in an if statement?

Comment: Well, there must be something wrong with my specs then, cos when I read the title I see `What is “=/” in ...`

Comment: that's a good one, apologies for using quotes around code. haha.

Comment: You know that "=/2" inside an if statement would blowup however, since it's not a string comparison.

Comment: On the other hand, / is more like the strike in ≠ and Haskell, for example, follows the same convention. And Pascal, which many used to learn to program in, uses `<>`. Algol also used something else. It is far from universal.